# ModuleNotFindError No module named 'sumolib' cuando intento ejecutar python3 en java

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, netbeans

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente comando en la terminak

```
python3 main.py "J1" "Red2Way.net.xml" "i"
```

funciona correctamente y me devuelve lo que estoy esperando.
Pero cuando lo ejecuto en java de la siguiente manera

```
    ProcToString pts=new ProcToString("python3","main.py","J1","Red2Way.net.xml","i");
    try {
        System.out.println(pts.runProcess());
        System.out.println(pts.hasResult());
        if (pts.hasResult()){
            String resultado = pts.getResult();
            System.out.println(resultado);
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Me da el siguiente error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>    import sumolibModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sumolib'
```

Obviamente el sumo lib si lo tengo instalado y por eso si ejecuta desde la terminal.
Estoy usando python 3.9 y ejecutando desde NetBeans.

Comment: Estas usando algún entorno virtual para python?

Comment: No estoy usando ningun entorno virtual